# Django Allauth executes request.POST on signup, but no redirect or email sent?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-allauth

This started happening yesterday (it was working fine before), I've retraced my steps and reversed any edits and it's still not working.

I'm using Allauth with Django and the generic signup form `/accounts/signup/` isn't redirecting to `verification_sent.html`.

An `email_confirm.html` is also not being sent to confirm the account.

I've set up an email backend to test on localhost and normally the emails come through fine via the terminal window. Now when I submit the form and `request.POST`, nothing happens.

No emails, no `verification_sent.html` page redirection.

The terminal isn't throwing any errors and says

`HTTP POST /accounts/signup/ 200`

How can I go about debugging this?

signup.html

```
<form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.password2|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.captcha|as_crispy_field }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id='signup_button'>Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserRegisterForm'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS=7
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
```

Comment: as i can see you study the django, did you need some help, many your questions has not the answer.

Comment: Hi @BearBrown nice to see you again :) Yes I ended up answering my own question, I've just marked it as correct below. It had to do with captcha.

Comment: @BearBrown Haha you are right, a lot of my questions don't have answers but I have solved most of them now.

Comment: glad to hear it, if need more help you can always add a direct comment to me for your new question, here many people who don't understand what they real do, but it is interesting to try help someone like you, who realy try to do reseach for any issues.(sorry for my english)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190680/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-trilla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by taking out the captcha for local testing as it was showing `Localhost is not in the list of supported domains for this site key.`